# Sqoop Export into Sql Server VS Bulk Insert into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop, bcp

I have a unique query regarding Apache Sqoop. I have imported data using apache Sqoop import facility into my HDFS files.

Next ,. I need to put the data back into another database (basically I am performing data transfer from one database vendor to another database vendor) using Hadoop (Sqoop).

To Put data into Sql Server , there are 2 options.

1) Using Sqoop Export facility to connect to my RDBMS,(SQL server) and export data directly.

2) Copy the HDFS data files (which are in CSV format) into my local machine using copyToLocal command and then perform BCP  ( or Bulk Insert Query) on those CSV files to put the data into SQL server database.

I would like to understand which is the perfect(or rather correct) approach to do so and which one of them is more Faster out of the two - The Bulk Insert or Apache Sqoop Export from HDFS into RDBMS. ??

Are there any other ways apart from these 2 ways mentioned above which can transfer faster from one database vendor to another.?

I am using 6-7 mappers (records to be transferred is around 20-25 millions)

Please suggest and Kindly let me know if my Question is unclear.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you do is ETL from one vendor to another, then going through Sqoop/HDFS is a poor choice. Sqoop makes perfect sense if the data originates in HDFS or is meant to stay in HDFS. I would also consider sqoop if the set is so large as to warrant a large cluster for the transformation stage. But a mere 25 million records is not worth it.

With SQL Server import it is imperative, on large imports, to achieve [minimally logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which require bulk insert. Although 25 mil is not so large as to make the bulk option imperative, still AFAIK sqoop, nor sqoop2, do not support bulk insert for SQL Server yet.

I recommend [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) instead. Is much more mature than sqoop, it has [bulk insert task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239.aspx) and has a [rich transformation featureset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137681.aspx). Your small import is well within the size SSIS can handle.

Comment: Thanks Remus, that answers my question. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Remus: If not for the purpose of ETL from one vendor to another, which option is best among BCP and SQOOP for the purpose of exporting from hive/hdfs to sql server.